# Does NFS have an intelligent cache

Tags: caching, nfs, prefetch

I have a question concerning the NFS cache. I have searched online about the NFS cache, but could not find the answer. Some said that NFS itself does not cache but the operating system may do some caching at the filesystem level. Is it true? Does NFS have a smart cache which can smart prefetch and/or smart commit?

Comment: Nfs has attribute cache. It keep metadata of server files. In addition there is also linux page cache that keep infornation. The 2nd one cannot be disabled. The attribute cache on nfs mount can be disabled.